# Is there a way to change the font color of the Release pipeline logs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Azure Devops Release pipeline logs, is there am option to change font text color say to red for exception.

Comment: I am afraid there is not option available to change the text color of the pipeline logs.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way you can change the color.

```
      echo "##[group]Beginning of a group"
      echo "##[warning]Warning message"
      echo "##[error]Error message"
      echo "##[section]Start of a section"
      echo "##[debug]Debug text"
      echo "##[command]Command-line being run"
      echo "##[endgroup]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MS Azure Pipelines have a variety of options to add colouring, and other fancy display options, to the log.  Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands).

Answer (score 2):

There are various logging commands which formats text. But there is no way to have free choice here. In terms of color formatting you could use these

```
- script: |
    echo "##[section]This would be green"
    echo "##[command]And this blue"
  displayName: 'Color formatting'
```

[image]

If you don't mind about prefixes in square braces you can use these:

```
- script: |
    echo "##[warning]Warning message"
    echo "##[error]Error message"
    echo "##[debug]Debug text"
  displayName: 'Color formatting'
```

[image]

There is an also way to group message. It is useful when you have longer text to be printed. You can then collpase/expand that message

```
- script: |
    echo "##[group]Beginning of a group"
    echo "##[warning]Warning message"
    echo "##[error]Error message"
    echo "##[section]Start of a section"
    echo "##[debug]Debug text"
    echo "##[command]Command-line being run"
    echo "##[endgroup]"
  displayName: 'Grouping'
```

[image]

[image]

All this information you can find here in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)